# What contra-rotating propellers would be appropriate for this engine?

Tags: propeller, paraglider

I am currently getting an X4 cylinder, 150cc, 4 stroke engine 3D CAD Modelled, this engine is initially being designed for Powered Paragliding (**PPG**), classified as experimental Aircraft, so no certification is required!

I have read several discussions here, that largely relate to large ridged winged Aeroplanes travelling at high ground speed.

PPG is a Low & Slow (22~75kph) Aviation sport, there are obvious differences with this project being;

Most PPG engines max. rev are from 7'000~12'000rpm.
Then a Re-drive is used to slow Prop down to approx. .88~.90 mach.

With a PPG, it is the Wing that sets the Speed in flight, **not the engine!**
A larger more powerful engine only provides a higher climb rate or maintain lever flight easier.

Most engines of similar capacity swing a 125cm (49/28") Prop at around 2'700rpm to under 3'000rpm.

The engine we are designing uses a unique engine that has replaced the 100yr old conventional crankshaft with a patented Contra-rotating Trilobe centre drive shaft (CDS) technology, that uses two trilobe cams, that strokes each Piston 6 times on One revolution, thus providing 3 combustions in two revolutions of CDS, this engine will not be revving over 3'500rpm maximum.

Engine is currently 12.5kg and 41cm width x 37cm high x 20cm deep.

**I am planing on using Two 100cm (40") Contra-Rotating propellers!**

[image: Raptor X4-150]

**I would appreciate it if anyone could assist/help me if this is an appropriate Sized Prop & what Pitch would be best ?**

Comment: "With a PPG, it is the Wing that sets the Speed in flight, not the engine!" This is true of all aircraft.

Comment: @Steve Not exactly. In a conventional aircraft, once you select a certain power setting and adjust stab/elevator trim until you are in level flight, the resulting speed is dependent on the power setting. In a PPG, there is no stabilizer, so level flight will always be at a fixed speed.

Comment: @Sanchises In a conventional aircraft, in straight and level flight, if the power setting is increased (and only this is changed), the aircraft will initially speed up, but then it will start climbing. It should stabilize back at the original speed, which is set by the trim.

Comment: Why do you think you need contra rotating propellors for an engine predicted to produce only 20hp?

Comment: @Steve True. I suppose the quote from the OP is a bit ambiguous, but I think he's hinting at the fundamental lack of horizontal trim rather than basic flight dynamics.

Comment: A contra-rotating prop is not needed, it is about making PPG flight a lot Safer, as it will eliminate Torque twist ...caused by one prop!as this engine 

As this engine does not have a normal crankshaft we can do this, unlike any other engine.

Comment: @Sanchises/@Steve, with a PPG, the Sink rate increases usually caused by  Paraglider speks/design, so an under powered engine will obviously need to rev higher & work harder to maintain level flight, Clime rate is very important if pilots want to climb out of a valley easier.

As yet we are unsure of the HP, Torque will be high enough to compensate.

Comment: Anyone with knowledge ...to assist me if 100cm Prop advice ?

Comment: Question: conventional 4-stroke radials have an odd number of pots, with your 4 cylinders and 6 strokes per revolution, won't you have the piston-gap problem?  Or is that the point of the tri-lobe cams?

Comment: A  Radial has a crankshaft & con rod and one revolution strokes a piston twice.

This engine does 3 full strokes (6), that is equal to 1 1/2 Combustions per 360 degree rotation, when you see our crankshaft it will make more sense.

Comment: [Click here to see How the Trilobes work](http://poweredparagliders.com.au/_BlackHawk/Engines/1.(4-stroke)_Raptor_X4-150/revani.gif)


This is image of the [Trilobes & Piston Plates](http://www.poweredparagliders.com.au/_BlackHawk/Engines/1.(4-stroke)_Raptor_X4-150/Revetec_Trilobe_X4v2_b.jpg)

Comment: Are you opposed to using a tri-prop? this would be difficult for a 2-bladed propellor.

Comment: No, I am not opposed to a three bladed propeller, in fact I understand that as both types are balanced during manufacturing, it will not make any difference in using either one.

Comment: In PPG applications, the saying goes, 3 blades are for show, as Usually a two blade are for Go, as a Timber prop usually provides better thrust as there is less flex.

I was thinking of using both, I am of the understanding the last propeller needs a higher pitch to clear the disturbed air of the first prop.

Comment: @TheRaptor I'm thinking size restrictions for this large motor. 2 prop will need much more cross-section than a 3 prop

Comment: Are you planning on releasing the design.

Comment: The Engine is still in CAD design phase, then FEA testing, and finally the release hopefully will happen before the end of this year. 
You can see more information on the [Raptor-150 Project here][1]: 


  [1]: http://www.poweredparagliders.com.au/_BlackHawk/Engines/1.(4-stroke)_Raptor_X4-150/Raptor_X4-150cc.html

Answer (score 2):

Contra-rotating props correctly address the problem of how torque
complicates the steering of a PPG.
(To solve this, others have even powered PPGs with large "quadcopters"
where two of the four props are counter-rotating,
despite the screaming of four small fast props.)

In conventional aviation two contra-rotating props typically have the
same diameter and pitch and speed.  For a PPG, keeping them the same size
is particularly useful to cancel torques.

To replace one prop with two, and otherwise keep everything the same,
we should not change the pitch speed or RPM, only the diameter,
to spread the thrust load evenly across both props.

The OP says that a similar engine powers a 49x28" prop at 2700 rpm.
The OP's engine redlines not much past that, so call the RPMs the same.
Then the prop pitch also remains the same, so prop diameter is the only thing left to vary.

Coaxial contra-rotating props are roughly 10% more efficient,
compared to non-coaxial props as on a conventional twin-engine airplane.
So each one of the pair has 45% of the load of the original single prop.

So each prop provides 45% of the thrust of the nominal 49x28" prop.
If all else is equal, thrust varies with the fourth power of diameter.
So we should scale the diameter of the 49x28" prop by 0.45<sup>1/4</sup> = 0.82.
So the engine should use a pair of 40x28" props.
Exactly the diameter that was guessed.